# Mirror remote SVN repository to remote GIT repository using SubGit

Tags: git, svn, subgit

We are in the process of migrating from SVN to Git, and we'd like to work with both, simultaneously for a while, that's why we need mutual synchronization. Changes on SVN should be mirrored on GIT and vice versa.

But, I'm facing a bit of a hiccup:
I have access to the following SVN repo:  https://svn.domain1.com/test_repo
and the following Git Repo: https://gitlab.domain2.com/test/test.git

Did anyone figure out a way in which you can install SubGit on a third server, and automatically mirror two SVN/GIT remote repositories?

From what I can see, I am only able to mirror the remote SVN on a local repository, not on a remote one like I need:

```
subgit configure --svn-url https://svn.domain1.com/test_repo /home/test.git
```

A command such as this would be useful, unfortunatelly "--git-url" is not a valid parameter.

```
subgit configure --svn-url https://svn.domain1.com/test_repo --git-url https://gitlab.domain2.com/test/test.git
```

Did anyone find a working solution in this case?

Comment: Currently this can't be done. The main problem is concurrent commit and push (changing the same files in different way)to the SVN and to the Git repositories simultaneously. When Git repository is local, SubGit controls its hooks and can reject Git push if a change conflicts with a change to SVN done at the same millisecond, making synchronization really safe. When Git repository is remote, SubGit doesn't control neither Git nor SVN. And if the changes in Git and SVN conflict, only human can choose between these changes. You could only ask your hosting provider to install SubGit into Git repo.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was helpful indeed. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.